# Alternate for Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, workflow-foundation

We are planning to start developing application in ASP.Net Core. We are having workflow related functionalities. As WF is not available for .Net Core, can you please let me know the alternate open source mechanism?

Even we are fine if we have something in NodeJS.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and following is the approach used:

Create a separate Workflow solution which consist of following projects:

1. Project.Workflow - Console project for Workflow XAML
2. Project.Common - Class Library for Workflow.Client, handles invoking, publishing, management etc

Once you create this you can now create a NuGet package for Project.Common and use it it any CORE project for example MVC UI project

Then in the MVC controller you can invoke your workflows